# Genymotion проблемы с воспроизведением звука

Tags: java, android, android-studio, genymotion, android-mediaplayer

Есть такой код(main_activity.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_button"
        android:text="@string/click_me"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(MainActivity.java):

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private MediaPlayer sound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.b_button);
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.cat_muc);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sound.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Код работает так - нажимаешь на кнопку и воспроизводится звук(мяу), тестил на вирутальном устройстве от android studio, там всё работает, закидывал на настоящий телефон, там тоже робит. Но почему на genymotion звук срабатывает только при клике на кнопку в первый раз, а при дальнейших нажатиях ничего нету?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gennymotion явно говорит в своем FAQ об известных проблемах
https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#sound-windows

Для вашего кода я бы добавил:

- проверку что player уже не проигрывается (скорее всего GennyMotion не завершает)
- делать Release в onStop

ПОдробнее https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#StateDiagram